# Is Array.prototype.map() being used properly if it does not return

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, functional-programming

The typical usage for the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method uses a callback  which is passed each element in an array sequentially, performs some operation on that element, and then returns a corresponding element for a new array. For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arrMap = arr.map(function(element) {
        return element * 2;
    })

console.log(arrMap) // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

I've found that in certain situations, when trying to maintain a functional coding style and avoid using loops, It can be useful to use the `.map()` method to without necessarily returning a value inside the callback. A contrived example of using `.map` to convert two arrays to an object:

```
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    obj = {},
    arr1.map(function(element, index) {
        obj[element] = arr2(index);
    });
```

What I am wondering is whether or not there is anything technically wrong with using `Array.prototype.map` without a `return` statement. Is this somehow against best practices, or is it fine to use `.map` in place of a loop or recursive function with this technique.

Comment: This will work but this is not what it is supposed to do, use **forEach** for this task.

Comment: But the entire point of the exercise is to avoid using a loop?

Comment: If you think **map** is not a loop, why do you think **forEach** is a loop.

Comment: You're correct, I'm sure that the natively both methods are implemented using loops - my point was entirely semantic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, `Array.prototype.map` takes an array and a function and returns another array. So, `map` is used to create a new array. In your second example, you are completely ignoring the returned array. You can check that like this

```
    ...
    temp = arr1.map(function(element, index) {
        obj[element] = arr2[index];
    });

console.log(temp);
```

Since you are not returning anything explicitly, JavaScript returns `undefined`, by default. So `temp` will be

```
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

This is unncessary. So, instead of `map`, you should use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in this case. This will not create the array, like `map` did.

```
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    obj = {};
    arr1.forEach(function(element, index) {
        obj[element] = arr2[index];
    });
console.log(obj);
```

Even better, **the best function to use in this case** is [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which can be used like this

```
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    obj = arr1.reduce(function(result, currentElement, index) {
        result[currentElement] = arr2[index];
        return result;
    }, {});

console.log(obj);
// { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 }
```

`reduce`, as the name suggests, takes an array of values and reduces that to a single value. In this case, we use `reduce` on `arr1` and it reduces `arr1`, on every iteration, by storing the current key and value in the `result` object, which is finally returned.

**Note:** Since you are using Node.js, you can install a functional programming library, like underscore or lodash and then do this task simply with [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object), like this

```
var _ = require("underscore"),
    arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(_.object(arr1, arr2));
// { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 }
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that I missed the applicability of .reduce(). Thanks.